# network delays and Application->ProcessMessages()

Tags: c++, networking, network-programming, winsock, c++builder

I am writing a networking DLL that I use in my C++Builder project.  This DLL works with remote FTP servers.  I noticed a strange behavior when `recv()` is called.  Sometimes it returns 0.  But in another thread when `recv()` is called on the same socket, data is received as expected.

What does this mean?  I also noticed that calling `Application->ProcessMessage()` inside the DLL thread speeds up data receiving.

But what is wrong? Doesn't `ProcessMessages()` just process window messages or am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: What is the returned value of `recv` function ? If it is `SOCKET_ERROR` then call `WSAGetLastError()` and report that.

Comment: @SS it returns 0, while in another thread it returns data received. The sockets are 100% same

Comment: the sockets is in non blocking mode. also i tryed nodelay turning on and off - same case.

Comment: @Sergey: if `recv()` returns 0, it means the connection was closed by the other party. If `recv()` returns `SOCKET_ERROR`, `WSAGetLastError()` should not return 0 unless you are doing something to reset the calling thread's error state after `recv()` exits but before calling `WSAGetLastError()`.

Comment: @Remy does not mean recv()=0 when system got PSH packet and no further data packets?

Comment: @Sergey: `recv()` will return 0 when the socket receives a `FIN` packet, indicating that no further data will be sent.

Comment: but standard error return is -1 for such moments, or i am wrong?

Comment: Why are you calling `recv` on the same socket from two different threads?

Comment: @Mike, i working with remote FTP. The request that program can make can appear in any thread. The network functions (and higher level) are surrounded with critical sections.

Comment: If you think no one has given you the answer, then it's probably a good time to post some sample code that illustrates the problem you’re having.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly and you are trying to `recv` on the same `SOCKET` in parallel threads then don't do that, there is nothing to gain from it. The data you are `recv` is already buffered by the underlying system and you are accessing that, the thing you could do is to make multiple buffers for the `recv` so that when it returns data you could pass one buffer to the "upper levels" for processing and use the other one for the new `recv` call. You can also use just one large buffer with notifications what is for processing and what part is being used for receiving. The system probably has locks that forbid multiple reading on the same socket and so the result in one `recv` is `0`. If it didn't have that you would probably end up with some almost randomly split data.

**EDIT:** Full and long explanation

I think that using multiple threads to read from a single socket is not useful
Sockets are a software regulated thing. You network device doesn't create any "connections", it just processes the data received and wraps/unwrapps them into `IP` (or any other 
supported Internet Layer) packets (the previous depending on the network device, some of them are almost entirely software emulated by the os and actually perform just the basic "write to tx-read rx" services but to us its the same deal) . The `WinSock2` service recognizes packets with specific data ( as you have already noticed ) so that you may use one network device for simultaneously 
communicating with multiple peers. `WinSock2` activly monitors the traffic before handing it out to you. In other words: when you are about to get a successfull `recv` the data 
was already there and the underlying system has checked the socket you used as a parameter in `recv` and only handed you over the data that has already been marked as the data 
for that socket. Reading with multiple threads from one socket (without the almost useless `MSG_PEEK`) would make the system, if it didn't have locks, copy unknown number of bytes 
to the location supplied in `recv` in the thread one and increment the internal pointer to data by number of copied bytes permanently, then, before whole data availible in the 
`recv` is copied at the location1, the other thread would kick in and copy also unknown number of bytes thus also incrementing the internal pointer to data by that many bytes. 
Result of this type of reading would ideally be half of the data stored from location supplied in thread 1, the other half starting from location supplied in thread 2. Since the ideal result is uncertain (time allocated by the system for theese two threads is not guarantied to be equal) you would end up with unsorted data without any means of sorting 
it, since the info that the underlying system uses for knowing what data belongs to which socket will not be able to you.

Being that your system is most likely faster than your network device I stand by my two solutions, first one prefered as I have been using this method for both big and small chunks of data transfer:

1. Make one reading thread per connected socket and one circular buffer, size of the buffer depends on the size of chunks you expect to receive and the time you will need to process the stuff further, save current read position, save "to process count", when data is received notify the thread/threads that it is supposed to process the data in the buffer, save the position of the data being used for reading, continue `recv` if there is buffer space not being processed else wait until there is (must implement this in case your computer chokes somewhere, in normal situations it shouldn't). You must sync the receiving thread with the processing thread/threads when they are accesing the "to_process_count" and "current read pos" vars as those will tell 
   you which bytes you can reuse in your circular buffer.
2. Create and connect one socket per desired reading thread so that the system will know how to regulate the data on its own

The thing you are refering too as random threads reading from a single socket, is maybe acievable through the following scenarios:

1 Thread Enumerates socket to see if there is data availible
when data is availible it uses some mutex to wait if some thread is already in the reading state starts a new thread to read **and** process the existing data

or it can be achieved with something like this

Thread does its `recv` as soon as it has done a successful `recv` (yey, the data is in the buffer) it starts another thread from some thread pool to do `recv` and continues to process data and end itself

Theese are the only ways I can imagine that "reading with multiple threads on a single socket" is achievable. Yes, there won't be multiple threads calling `recv` at the same time

Sorry for the long post, the spelling and grammar errors and hope this helps you a bit

Comment: Yes, that is the problem i think, but what i can do to recv() data i should recieve in thread 1, but received only in thread 2? I am using parallel threads to talk with FTP, with critical sections of course, but sometime i cant recv() response from FTP in thread 1 where i send() my command, the reply will be in thread 2. What i can do here?

Comment: One Reading thread per socket is all that you get, if you absolutely want to talk with the FTP in parallel (one valid reason is multiple stuff needed at the same time and you don't want to route data yourself) you will need to create and connect one socket per thread. I have never tried that as I have always been the developer of both server and client in my apps and have always routed the data myself but that seems as the way to go

Comment: so you think using socket in parallel threads is dangerous or erroneous or you mean this is faster way? I really think that i just need to call some one maybe two functions and i can get response in thread wich sent the request. You are right about system buffers or make some layer on top of socket wich is changed every time thread switches. I tryed TCP_NODELAY/nagle on/off, SO_KEEPALIVE on/off, changing buffer sizes, SO_OOBINLINE on/off but it not affects this condition, but really change somethinh other.

Comment: I tryed also SwitchToThread(), Sleep(). I know solution should be in practice, because this is very massively used technique to use same socket in random threads. So the question is what user app can call in windows environment to solve buffering/this problem.

Comment: thank you for good explanation, but the socket recv() is around critical section, so only one thread can execute recv() - so the data should be in non-random form but in protocol scenario. But still i have situations when one thread (at time1) can not recv anything while another thread (at time1 too) can recv data.Still can't figure this out...

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that socket is properly bound to the handle you are using in `recv` function.
You cannot speedup data reception, unless there is channel to receive the data.

Comment: its a fact, the sockets are 100% same.